# Write different lines to file

Tags: java, file

I have this method that writes to a file every time it's called:

```
public void writeToFile(String ins) {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    bw.write(ins);
    bw.newLine();

    bw.close();
    fw.close();
}
```

But it only writes on the very first line of the file.

So, if I called it once with "Hello" and then again with "World", the file would contain "World", but the result I'm looking for is:

> Hello
>
> World

I tried using `BufferedWriter.newLine()` before and after writing the string but the result is the same?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `FileWriter`? Check out the second argument to the constructor: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean) (In other words, you want to `append` to a file, not write/overwrite it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: Beyond that: you got various answers by now; please pick one to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) of FileWriter:

> FileWriter(File file, boolean append) 
>   Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

and you see, that you need to set the append value to true:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is: your code does what it is supposed to do - it uses a FileWriter, which by default will **create** a new, empty file; it writes one string; and closes the FileWriter.

If you want to write more than one line; you either have to

- use the [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) in APPEND mode when doing *later* writes (by using that second, boolean argument for the FileWriter constructor with `true`)
- change your method to take a list of strings, and write all of them at once

Comment: I like that statement : "your code does what it is supposed to do" It is usually true, but the dev don't code what it is supposed to be done ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a escape character:

```
\b Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
```

I recommend you to use resource try to allow java to close the file when it will necessary

```
public void writeToFile(String ins) {

    String fileName= "file.txt";

    try (FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(fileName, true)) {

        fileWritter.write(ins + "\r\n");

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
```

give to this method a empty string "" to insert in the file a "Enter"